# Make use of a "deleted" column in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Instead of actually deleting a row on delete I want to update a column called "deleted" with the time that the delete happened (and maybe even set the "deleteduserid" column). Then of course, on all object->find operations I want to exclude all the deleted rows. Is this possible or am I crazy?

Comment: No, that's perfectly possible and you're not crazy. Any specific problems putting this into action? :o)

Comment: i do this for lots of sites, you just then have to make user to add WHERE deleted ='0' to a lot of querries

Comment: @Dagon Not having to worry about appending "where deleted = 0" to every query is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the `beforeFind()` model callback to filter rows where deleted=1. I would check the `$queryData['conditions']`, appending `$queryData['conditions']['Model.deleted'] = 0` if 'Model.deleted' or 'deleted' is not set.

For more details, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/76/Callback-Methods.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use this behavior http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mariano/2007/04/16/soft-delete-behavior

Comment: Never heard the term "soft delete" before. That might have made my googleing easier. Thanks.